# Javascript/Jquery: How do I modify this script to avoid have to use a <A> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of the issues I have with this script is that I have to have a link tag to get the `rel` from it.  I am looking at doing descriptions when user mouseover's a table row.

What I need: If TD has `desc`, append text.
`<td desc="blah blah blah">`

```
 this.screenshotPreview = function () {
     xOffset = 20;
     yOffset = 30;

     $("tr:has(a[desc])").hover(function (e) {
         var text = $(this).find('a').attr('desc');
         $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'>" + text + "</p>");
         $("#screenshot")
             .css("top", (e.pageY - yOffset) + "px")
             .css("left", (e.pageX + xOffset) + "px")
             .fadeIn("fast");
     },function () {
         this.title = this.t;
         $("#screenshot").remove();
     });
     $("a.screenshot").mousemove(function (e) {
         $("#screenshot")
             .css("top", (e.pageY - yOffset) + "px")
             .css("left", (e.pageX + xOffset) + "px");
     });
 };


 // starting the script on page load
 $(document).ready(function () {
     screenshotPreview();
 });
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zD99p/1/  (in jsfiddle, it still uses `rel` instead of `desc`.  You can code it either way, I can change that with no problem)

Comment: You want hover on `TR`?

Comment: hover on `<td>`..I changed it because of typo.  But I only want it to append text if the `<td>` has a `desc` attribute. `<td desc="">`

Comment: Why not use the standard HTML5 "data-" attribute and $('...').data()?

Comment: Because my system isn't coded in html5

Comment: jQuery can use it, regardless of whether it's html5 or not.

Comment: There is no `desc` attribute on `td` elements?

Comment: @Bergi - I know there isn't.  I wasn't aware that I could still use html5 attributes without the document being html5.  So I was going to create my own.  I'm use rel for something else, so decided to create a desc attribute.  But now that I know I can use html5 data- attribute, I'm not using `desc` anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `data-` attributes:

http://jsfiddle.net/MWkXJ/

```
<td data-desc="..."></td>
```

---

```
$("td[data-desc]").hover(function (e) {
     var text = $(this).data('desc');
     //...
```

Comment: Do you know why when you hover over it, it appears, if you move mouse somewhere else, and then bring mouse back and hover again, it adds an undefined title attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
...
 $("td[desc]").hover(function (e) {
     var text = $(this).attr('desc');
     $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'>" + text + "</p>");
...
```

And change html to this:

```
<td desc="blah blah">content ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6yMNM/

Comment: While this does work, @Bergi pointed out that `<td>` elements do not have a `desc=""` attribute. It is invalid markup...

Comment: Or avoid having to do any JavaScript at all and use a native `title` attribute. I think those are valid on almost any element...

Answer (score 0):

in your JSFIDDLE you missed a closing `</a>`. I changed that and changed the `<a>`to a `<div>`and it worked. look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zD99p/1/).

Comment: Question __How do I modify this script to avoid have to use a <A> tag?__